# Where can I find drivers for my Sony Vaio touchpad?

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, scrolling, sony-vaio

The other day while I was clearing some space on my Sony Vaio PCG-71312L, I accidentally deleted the touchpad's driver. The mouse itself is fine, it's just that the scrolling is not working.

I looked around for the CD that came with the laptop, but couldn't find it. Also, I tried searching for the drivers, but with no success. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve installing softwares, the driver will suffice.

Comment: [Sony Support](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/model-find.pl?mdl=71312L&PRODTYPE=4,17). Do you have a more precise model number?

Comment: I can't find my model number in there :/, any other suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Sony laptops use Alps touchpads.  This is a link to a WIN7 64 bit driver package [ALPS Windows 7 x64](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-download.pl?mdl=VPCEB11FMBI&upd_id=5368&os_group_id=6)  You should be able to find an x86 driver with a bit of digging at Sony Support as mentioned by @slhck

Comment: ill look it up, and its okay I have the 64 bit WIN, but thx anyways :D

Comment: It's appropriate just for VPCEB11FM/BI Model as you can see in top of the page in red color "IMPORTANT: This file is only for use with the models identified. Not all models are sold in all countries." Anyway i downloaded My VAIO version VPCF12THX/H but when i try to install it warn about this program is just for windows vista/windows 7. My VAIO has Windows 7 Ultimate 64Bit and i don't understand why i saw this message.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have driver but it's not work for various issues. In my case i don't know why touch panel did stop to response on some actions like scrolling page when touching corners. I searched and finally this simple guide movie helped me. you just need to get default setup settings if you have same trouble. this video must be help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wkgBSL6Z4BU
Good Luck.